# $k$-forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

Given an expression like
$$
dx_1\wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_4 \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\3\ \end{bmatrix} \ , \ \begin{bmatrix} 4\\5\\6 \end{bmatrix} \ , \ \begin{bmatrix} 7\\8\\9 \end{bmatrix} \right) \ ,
$$
does this make sense? With only the given information, it seems that it is implied that we have a 3-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$, in which case it does not make much sense. But why can't we just add a fourth (zero) coordinate to each of the column vectors and compute the 3-form on $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: But you can add the zero coordinate in four different places. Which one do you choose?

Comment: Some more context would be nice to have. It is not common to truncate zeros from column vectors like that. More likely is that $dx_4$ should have been $dx_3$.

Comment: @user75064: No, I meant $dx_4$. My textbook had some questions similar to what I put and I know the expression does not make sense as is. However, I was curious about why we cannot add a fourth component to the vectors.

Comment: You can, it's just not clear why you would want to do it. It looks like an arbitrary manipulation. The result will be zero, by the way, because the form has $dx^4$ and your vectors will feed zero into that component.

Comment: @AlexP. I see how this can be an issue...

Comment: @user75064: I guess my main curiosity is in why we would just say that it doesn't make sense instead of defining such an expression to equal 0.

Comment: @5space Perhaps because it's pointless to define something unless you are going to use it? By the way, if zeroes are inserted as the 3rd row instead of the 4th, the expression evaluates to 45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the question does not make sense.